# How to add script before body element

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems to be very simple, but I can understand where I miss the thing:

```
var string1 = document.createElement('script');
$(string1).attr('type', 'text/javascript');

$('body').before($(string1));
```

In jquery 2.0.3 version, it works perfect, but I need it works in 1.8.3 version. Where am I wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Add it to the <head> element.

Comment: The body element isn't allowed a script element as a sibling. Why are you trying to put it there?

Comment: @Quentin: source for that?

Comment: What is the use case for adding scripts "before" body at runtime?

Comment: Seconded @ThomasJunk - what's the point of this?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari — [`<!ENTITY % html.content "HEAD, BODY">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-HTML) - nowhere else allows a body element as a child node, the HTML element doesn't allow a script element as a child node.

Comment: @Quentin my wrong, I misread the "sibling" part, sorry!

Comment: @Quentin people put scripts in the body all the time. See ["Local declaration of a scripting language"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html) in the spec.

Comment: @dhsto that's my same mistake, but he said **sibling** and not **child**, hence he is right.

Comment: @dhsto Yeah... **inside the body**, not as a sibling of the body.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari oh hahaha yeah he's right (I made that same "sibling" == "child" thought in my head). Well you know, it's monday morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to

```
$('body').before($(string1));
```

Should actually be

```
$('body').prepend($(string1));
```

This will add the script as child of the body, before all other elements.

If instead with `before` you mean, not in the body, then it should be

```
$('head').append($(string1));
```

In fact as @Quentin says in the comments, `script` tags cannot go directly in `html` tag.

Also please see the docs for both [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) and [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) as they have a completely different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to add a script before the `body` element. That would lead to invalid HTML.

You should probably add it to the `head` instead.

```
$('head').append(string1);
```

*Note: You should really be careful when naming your variables. `string1` is misleading as it does not reference a string but a `script` element.*